# Publish iOS app to App Store on behalf of client

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, submission

I have

- An apple id
- The source code
- A Distribution Certificate generated for my apple id using client's developer portal
- A Provisioning profile for the newly created App ID and my distribution certificate

My client dont want to share his apple id credentials with me. I am able to archive the product in Xcode, but am not able to submit it to App Store.

Can i directly submit it to the store with the above details i've got?

Or Can i build IPA file and share it with client, so he can submit to App Store?

Is there any other alternative ways we can submit the app to store (other than sharing his credentials)

Kindly explain the answer (with step by step guide if possible).

Thanks

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41130669/3681880) was also very helpful. Apparently the client has to have a organization Apple Developer Account, not an individual one.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For those who needs to do the same on behalf of clients, here are the steps i've followed...

**What i had**

1. An apple developer account (with no Developer Program Enrollment)

**What client had**

1. An apple developer account (with Apple Developer Program Enrollment for Company)

As far as app distribution is concerned, apple have 2 systems: Member Center (for Certificates, Profiles, App IDs etc) and ITunes Connect (for publishing your app to app store and further management of the app).

I need access to both ITunes Connect & Member center for distributing on behalf of client.

1. In Member Center, client should give you Team Admin Role. [[steps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH16-SW2)]
2. In ITunes connect, client should give you Developer Role / Admin Role for the app. If Developer Role, given u can only upload the build, to submit app for review you'll need to ask the client. If Admin role, basically you can do almost everything upto Submitting the app for review. [[steps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SettingUpUserAccounts.html)]
3. Now you can create certificates, profiles, app ids through Member Center (you can create certificates & profiles in Xcode also. But App IDS should be created through Member Center).
4. Create App Record in ITunes Connect using the same bundle ID used for App ID creation.
5. Upload your build through Xcode
6. Submit for review through Itunes Connect

> This is what i did for submitting the app. If you find any mistakes/better alternatives, pls comment below, so i'll update the answer.

Comment: You are asking the client the full admin access to his account. A serious company will never give you that kind of power. It's name and other apps depend on not sharing these kind of credentials

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to do the following:

1. Build the app using the distribution cert of the client
2. Archive the app using XCode (it's in the same menu as the build
   options)
3. When the archive is done it will open the Archive
   Organizer
4. Select the newly created archive and export it. The
   first option in exporting is the 'Save for iOS App Store
   Deployment'.
5. This will create a directory on your mac that contains the bits
   and pieces your client will need to upload it.
6. Zip that directory and transfer to your client. They should be able
   to use the web-interface in iTunes connect to upload the app and
   complete the app submission process.

Answer (score 3):

> ... Or Can i build IPA file and share it with client, so he can submit to App Store?

To answer your question, you can build the app and provide to your client for them to submit the app.

For building the app (.ipa) you need to get the Provisioning profile & Certificate (.p12) corresponds to Apple developer program from the client.

I have done this for many of our clients and solution is working. In fact few of the clients they have an internal portal with the predefined process.

In case, if anyone of you have queries on this response comment below and I shall try to answer.

Note: when signing remember to choose use local signing assets in order to avoid giving apple id credentials.

Comment: Can you please provide the steps?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to have your client add you under User and Roles in iTunes Connect. There is a developer role now that can limit access to a certain app and restricts it to the below:

[image: App Features]

Comment: That's true. However, the client may give permission to other users ONLY if it's a company account. If it's s personal account, then you can't give access to other people.

Comment: do i need to purchase Apple's Developer Program?

Comment: You do not need to pay for the Developer Program. Only have an account. This works even if they have a personal account now.

Comment: @Jeremiah: Does adding me as an Admin in Itunes Connect will automatically add me into their team in Member Center too?

Comment: No, Member Center is separate. If their account is corporate they can add you to the Member Center as well. You can't have multiple members if their account is person.

Answer (score 0):

As of Summer of 2017, Which is after this was initially asked) The developer and the app producer name must be the same. Thus just have them spend the 
$99 a year and get a Dev account that they add you to to Develop / manage.

Here is a short and detailed explanation: [1]: http://www.goodbarber.com/blog/your-client-s-developer-accounts-vs-your-own-a856/

Here is how to tranfer if already in app Store under your account:[1]: https://support.appmachine.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000012284-Transfer-your-app-to-another-iOS-Developer-Account

Answer (score -1):

You need to use IP distribution with iOS to build IPA to upload to the App Store

Answer (score -1):

According to the description the simplest way would be to submit the app on your own behalf and as soon as you pass the certification to transfer the published app to your client from iTunes Connect dashboard.