# How do i create a provisioning profile when my role is set to App Manager

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment, provisioning-profile, testflight

I am developing a iOS App for a friend. Now when i want so publish the app via TestFlight i get the error that i need to obtain a provisioning profile in order to proceed. Now is it possible to create a provisioning profile as an App Manager? He would give me his credentials to login to his account and i could simply create one, but shoudln´t it work as well when he set my role to app manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41080943/how-to-create-provisioning-profile-for-client-app).

Shortly:

> You need to be added to the Team of their Apple-Developer-Account with at least Team-Admin privileges to be able to do all aspect of development & distribution.