# Generate Production IPA without Developer account (base on profile and certificate)

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning-profile, ipa

anyone know to generate Production IPA without developer account in detail??
Client doesn't want to share Developer account detail with me, he gave me just provisioning profile and certificate

Using only profile and certificate can we generate IPA ??

Comment: The client doesn't have to share their account detail with you... they just have to make you a Team Member with Admin role. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35054038/6257435

Comment: You should have the P12, Provisioning profile and CErt for that profile . Use that will be sufficient to make an IPA. Or else use xcbuild tools from xcode to do without logging in to Dev account .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create a signed distribution build, your client would need to provide you with 3 things: the provisioning profile, the distribution certificate, and the **private key associated with the distribution certificate**. With those 3 files, you would be able to set up your Xcode project for manual code signing.  Select the provisioning profile the client provided and then do a distribution build.

Alternatively, you can provide the client an ipa that you have signed and have them resign it themselves, but to make it easier you would want to use a tool like iResign.

Finally, most companies who have a 3rd party do their development will add you as an admin role on their Apple developer account.  It would allow you to use Xcode's automatic code signing to create the build.  You would simply change the team in your project settings to be the client's account, and Xcode would do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Per @wottie's Answer

> your client would need to provide you with 3 things: the provisioning
> profile, the distribution certificate, and the private key associated
> with the distribution certificate.

Not to get confused, basically, you need only two things

1. Provisioning Profile
2. Distribution Certificate i.e. Signing Certificate

   For **private key associated with the distribution certificate** you would need to have this Distribution certificate in .p12 format, which comes with the private key. if it's password protected, you would need to ask for a password as well.

### **Provisioning Profile**

You can download it from Apple and needs to be installed in XCode.

### Distribution Certificate

This needs to be exported from the Account-Holder/Admin's computer, who originally created the Provisioning Profile. it should be in .p12 format. which needs to be installed on your Mac.

That's it, you should be all set.

Answer (score -1):

I think all what you need is those 2, provisioning profile & certificate. You can import your provisioning profile on Xcode and then it automatically links the associated signing certificate for you.

Comment: Yes i know we can import certificates but  is there any way to generate production build (that i can give to client to upload in itunes store) ???

Comment: Yes you can. Make sure you have the production distribution certificate and App Store provisioning profile. So once you archive the product you can get the IPA and share it with the client.. After sharing the ipa, we have 2 options to upload the IPA either through xcode (or) application loader thats your client headache.

Comment: You would also need the private key.  without it, you can't use the certificate to sign the binary.

Answer (score -2):

As I know , I hope it is not possible. You have to configure your system with that developer account then only you can get IPA .But I am not sur about it.